# During a video stream, how can i get chunk?

Tags: roku, brightscript

Does anyone know which place store chunk in ROKU? and how to get chunk using a code.

Answer (score 1):

Roku '[Video](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/media-playback-nodes/video.md)' node provides two fields to access metadata about the stream which is currently being played -

'**streamingSegment**' and '**downloadedSegment**'.

'*streamingSegment*' contains the information about the chunk that is currently being played and '*downloadedSegment*' contains information about the next chunk going to be played. Actually '*downloadedSegment*' data is copied to '*streamingSegment*' for chunk is being played and '*downloadedSegment*' starts storing the next chunk.

'***downloadedSegment***' is an associative array and **contains metadata about chunk(SegSize, SegType, Sequence etc.)**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer position, duration, segBitrateBps, segSequence, SegStartTime, and segUrl.